# Changing the configured target enviornment in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I've spent quite a few hours trying to change the target of vite and nitro to 'esnext via the nuxt.config.ts file.

This is my current nuxt.config.ts file

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: ['@/assets/scss/appStyles.scss'],
  //I cant mess with the Nuxt tailwindwidnd:{} file Oof or daisy will not work
  
  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: ['@nuxt/image', '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', '@nuxtjs/robots','@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt', '@pinia/nuxt'],
  ssr: true,
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  nitro: {
    esbuild: {
      options: {
        target: 'esnext',
      },
    },
  },
  vite: {
    esbuild: {
      tsconfigRaw: {
        compilerOptions: {
          target: 'esnext',
        },
      },
    },
  },

});
```

I dont know whats going on it keeps throwing this error

`Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

```
    node_modules/...
    const fs = /* #__PURE__ */ await import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ "fs");`
```

I've tried changing the nuxt.config.ts file and directly chaning the node modules vite file. after chaing the node modules vite file to es2022 the code runs fine but after I run yarn install it resets the constants.js file back to

```
const ESBUILD_MODULES_TARGET = [
    'es2020',
    'edge88',
    'firefox78',
    'chrome87',
    'safari14',
];
```

causing the error again to happen.